# How to bind Checkboxes with Chips in Vue js(Two way Binding)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Im a newbie in Vue Js.
The problem is on selecting an dropdown from form,options are coming in form of checkbox in a div,on selecting of checkbox, chips should display with the checkbox label.But here checkbox is automatically  getting selected and chips are getting displayed,But after selecting an checkbox chips should display and on closing the chips checkbox should get Deselect.This is expected but not happening.Here is the my code.Kindly help.

```
   <template>
    <div id="app">
     <v-layout row wrap>
         <v-flex v-for="chip in chips" xs12 sm4 md4>
          <v-checkbox   :label="chip.name" v-model="chip.text"></v-checkbox>
          //  checkbox not working
          </v-flex>
        <div class="text-xs-center">
       <v-select
       :items="dataArr"
        v-model="sensorDM"
       label="Select"
      class="input-group--focused"
     item-value="text"
     v-change="call(sensorDM)"
       ></v-select>
       <v-chip
          v-for="tag in chips"
          :key="tag.id"
          v-model="tag.text"
          close
        >
        {{ tag.name }}
        </v-chip> 
        <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
      name: 'Creation',
      data: () => ({
       chips: [{
          id: 1, text: 'Device 1', name: 'Device 1'
        }, {
          id: 2, text: 'Device2', name: 'Device 2'
        }],
        chip1: false,
        chip2: true,
        dataArr: []
      }),
      created () {
        let self = this
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/devices')
    .then(function (response) {
     self.fData(response.data.result)
    })
      },
      methods: {
      fData: function (message) {
      let self = this  
      message.forEach(function (el, i) {
        self.dataArr.push(el.sDM.name)
      })
    },
        call (mes) {
          let self = this
          axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/part1/Models/' + mes)
    .then(function (res) {
      self.resObj = res.data.response
      self.resObj.forEach(function (el, i) {
        el['text'] = el.name
        el['isOpen'] = 'false'
      })
      self.chips = self.resObj
    })
        },
        submit(){
             console('hjkh')
        }    
      }
    }
```

Hi I have edited the code and added the function call from created()

Comment: are you able to setup a JSFiddle or CodePen to make the test easier?

Comment: Okay @MarceloBezerra

Comment: https://codepen.io/Success98/pen/MGqyPw @MarceloBezerra The values are dynamically populating

Comment: Is this codepen snippet even working? I can see you're pointing axios requests to localhost

Comment: Where do you close `v-flex` tag? It will make different. I can't guess your code now. Please make the syntax correctly.

Comment: @ittus Done Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to do like this https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/VxGjgN

```
<div id="app">
   <v-flex v-for="chip in chips" :key="chip.id" xs12 sm4 md4>
      <v-checkbox :label="chip.name" v-model="chip.selected"></v-checkbox>
      <v-chip
         v-model="chip.selected"
         close>
         {{ chip.name }}
      </v-chip>
   </v-flex>
   <div class="text-xs-center">
   </div>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      chips: [{
      id: 1, text: 'Device 1', name: 'Device 1', selected: false
    }, {
      id: 2, text: 'Device2', name: 'Device 2', selected: false
    }],
    chip1: false,
    chip2: true,
    }
  }
})
```

I added `selected` attribute, because by default v-checkbox and v-chip value are boolean.

Comment: Hi @ittus Im  facing the same old issue,can u please check and suggest me the solution

Comment: Did you check https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/VxGjgN? Is it your expectation?

Comment: yes it is my requirement,statically its coming but dynamically the checkboxes are getting checked and im unable to close the chips also :(

Comment: Dynamically means after getting response from 'localhost'?

Comment: yes after getting response once it hits the database from localhost

Comment: If it's the case, you need to update your code. axios call in `created()` hook do nothing. `call` methods is not call in your code above. It's impossible to inspect until you correct your code.

Comment: `call` method is not called from anywhere? Data in `dataArr` is not used?

Comment: I didn't see where it is used in your code above. Just see declaration

Comment: I  have a added it.Please check

Comment: @Success your v-model of the select is binding to the sensorDM variable which is not even existing in your vue component. I would highly recommend you to check out the  docs + style guide.

Everything is documented really good!!

[Vue Docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/),
[Vue Style Guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

I just super simplified your codepen to show how to do this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYMNxy?editors=1010

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
   <div v-for="chip of chips" :key="chip.id" xs12 sm4 md4>
     <input type="checkbox" v-model="chip.selected">
     <label for="checkbox">{{ chip.name }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
   chips: [
     { id: 1, text: 'Device 1', name: 'Device 1', selected: false},
     { id: 2, text: 'Device2', name: 'Device 2', selected: true}
   ]
  })
});
```

For you the checkboxes are always selected because your v-model is bound to the chip.text. I added a selected property to the chips so that you can bind to chip.selected.

I hope this helps!

Also a tip from my side, the guides from vue.js are super helpful and really nicely documented, please check them out:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

kr,
Georg

Comment: Thank you Burgi for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I tried one last time to understand your usecase and to show you in a very simplified version without vuetify and axios how to achieve what I think you want to achieve.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmJoYV?editors=1010

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="v-layout" row wrap>
       <div class="text-xs-center">
          <select
              v-model="selectedDevice"
              @change="getChips(selectedDevice)">

            <option 
                v-for="device of devices"
                :key="device.id">
                {{device.name}}
            </option>
          </select>
        <br>
       </div>

       <div id="v-flex"
            v-for="chip in chips" xs12 sm4 md4>

            <input id="v-checkbox" 
                   type="checkbox"
                   v-model="chip.selected"
            >
            <label for="v-checkbox">{{ chip.name }}</label>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
   devices: [],
   chips: [],
   selectedDevice: {}
  }),
  created () {
    // faked calling axios to get the devices and returned 2 hardcoded devices
    // axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/devices')
    this.devices =  [
     { id: 1, text: 'Device 1 text', name: 'Device 1'},
     { id: 2, text: 'Device2 text', name: 'Device 2'}
    ];
  },
  methods: {
    getChips (device) {

      console.log(device);
      // faked calling axios to get whatever you wanna get here
      // axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/part1/Models/' + mes)

      // Please ignore the if and else that is just there because
      // I am faking the axios calls that you would do!!
      if(device === 'Device 1') {
        this.chips =  [
          { id:1, name:"Chip_WH", selected: true}, 
          { id:2, name:"Chip_EH", selected: false}
        ];
      }
      else {
        this.chips = [
          { id:1, name:"Chip_BL", selected: false}, 
          { id:2, name:"Chip_CK", selected: true}
        ];
      }
    }
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Burgi for trying out the solution