# How to use v-model with checkbox in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In vue2 js, I want to use a checkbox with a v-model.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="test" :checked="selected"/>
```

I want the value of the checkbox to be `test`, however I want the 2 way binding with the prop called `selected` which is a boolean. However the above only does 1 way binding. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: could you provide more code and more details please?

Comment: A standard checkbox is like this `<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" checked>` and `v-model` seems to alter the `value` attribute. So how would that work when the `checked` attribute needs to be 2-way bind?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350254/how-to-bind-checkboxes-with-chips-in-vue-jstwo-way-binding

Comment: thats using a framework, im just talking about regular vue.

Answer (score 17):

Use `v-model` instead of `:checked`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" value="test" v-model="selected">
  <div>Selected: {{selected}}</div>
</div>
```